# custom accumulator class in spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'd like to define an accumulator in pyspark which is of type `List` and accumulate string values for worker nodes. Here is the code I have :

```
class ListParam(AccumulatorParam):
 def zero(self, v):
    return []
 def addInPlace(self, acc1, acc2):
    acc1.extend(acc2)
    return acc1
```

I then define an accumulator of this type as below

```
accu = sc.accumulator([], ListParam())
```

and then add different values to it in the executors as follows

```
accu.add("abc")
```

I'd like the value `abc` to appear as just one value in the accumulator but the accumulator adds three different values (one pr character) and when I look at the `accu` value in the driver it looks like `['a','b','c']`. How can I change it such that it doesn't add each character as a separate entry in the accumulator?

--------------edit----------------

I defined another custom class for my accumulator as follows

```
class VectorAccumulatorParam(AccumulatorParam):
 def zero(self, value):
    return [0.0] * len(value)
 def addInPlace(self, val1, val2):
    for i in range(len(val1)):
        val1[i] += val2[i]
    return val1
```

and within the worker I have the following code

```
global accu
accu += [accuracy]
```

but when I print the `accu` in the driver, it is empty. Anything wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as you, saw this question and worked with your code. The following code runs on a HDP 2.5 Cluster with (Py)Spark 2 and worked for me.

I took your class and changed it to append a string.

```
from pyspark.accumulators import AccumulatorParam
class ListParam(AccumulatorParam):
    def zero(self, v):
        return []
    def addInPlace(self, variable, value):
        variable.append(value)
        return variable
```

Then i created a accumulator variable and a test dataframe:

```
accu = sc.accumulator([], ListParam()) 
rdd = sc.parallelize([(0,1), (0,1), (0,2), (1,2), (1,10), (1,20), (3,18), (3,18), (3,18)]) 
df=rdd.toDF(['id','score'])
```

For the program i am working on, i have to repartition my dataframe to an individual size. So i tried this as well:

```
df.repartition(2)
```

After that i created a worker function, which will append a string to the accumulator list:

```
def worker(row):
    global accu
    accu.add("Moin")
```

Now i can call the foreach loop of the datafame (each partition is a task):

```
df.foreach(worker)
```

Every task append an item to the list with his own string list:

```
>>> accu
Accumulator<id=66, value=[['Moin', 'Moin', 'Moin', 'Moin'], ['Moin', 'Moin', 'Moin', 'Moin', 'Moin']]>
```

So i have to add every sub-list into a result-list

```
res = []
for i in range(0, len(accu.value)):
    res += accu.value[i]
```

Result:

```
>>> res
['Moin', 'Moin', 'Moin', 'Moin', 'Moin', 'Moin', 'Moin', 'Moin', 'Moin']
```

Comment: Brilliant. Good job, mate

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to explicitly tell spark to perform your operations that deal with the accumulator? As you should know, [spark's operations are lazy](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#rdd-operations), and many times you need to call rdd.collect() to actually perform your mappings